# google app engine python for loop counter

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2

How to keep count of for loop in google app engine. Like in Django {forloop.counter}, I have used this

```
  {% for user in users %}
     {{forloop.counter}}
  {%endfor%}
```

but this giver error as :

```
UndefinedError: 'forloop' is undefined
```

Need help with Syntax/App Engine

Library:

```
 libraries:
 - name: jinja2
 version: latest
```

Comment: updated the question. its jinja2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Jinja2 templates, you can access a [loop counter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#for) with:

```
{{loop.index}}
```

(which is 1-indexed like Django's `forloop.counter`; for 0-indexed use `loop.index0`)